# Blank screen on login after upgrading to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, 15.04

I recently upgraded from 14.10 to 15.04, and now I can no longer log in. `lightdm` works, and I get as far as putting in my password, and it appears to be logging in, but after a few seconds the screen goes black. The mouse cursor still moves but otherwise the UI is unresponsive.

My problem seems very similar to this bug report:

https://lists.launchpad.net/desktop-packages/msg101978.html

including the Xid errors logged in the `dmesg` buffer, but I'm on a later version of `compiz` and I don't believe there's a previous version available to downgrade to, without reinstalling 14.10 completely. Unfortunately, I'm at a loss where to even look for what the problem might be.

Is there something I can do to recover the system, or should I just grab what I can over ssh, format and start over?

Comment: Enter a TTY by pressing `Ctrl` + `ALT` + `F2`. Login here and run these commands: `sudo apt-get remove --purge unity ubuntu-desktop lightdm`, `sudo apt-get install unity ubuntu-desktop lightdm`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`.

Comment: I have ssh access, is it safe to do these remotely?

Comment: Yes, but it's better to do it at the computer.

Comment: The problem isn't anything important: they popup all the time.

Comment: yeah, it was an old one. I cleared out /var/crash and it stopped happening, but the behavior is the same; dm comes up, I log in, it thinks for a while, then black.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`. With Linux, it's just a matter of running any command you can think of until it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, Logging in the terminal mode (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and running the command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

and rebooting fixed my problem.